# How to pass an NULL (or empty) array to a JDBC callableStatement (that expects an Array)

Tags: arrays, jdbc, null, callable-statement

I'm having trouble passing a NULL value to a JDBC stored function (using a callable statement) that expects an Array type. This is only a problem if I'm trying to set the IN parameter to NULL (eg., I can create and pass an empty array, but I shouldn't have to do that).

For example, I can do this as a work-around:

```
callableStatement.setObject(index, callableStatement.getConnection.createArrayOf("numeric", Array().asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]))
```

But this bothers me. First of all, there is supposed to be an API for passing NULL arrays. Second of all, I'm creating an empty array for no good reason (and I'll have to create the **correct array type** so this is not a one-liner, I'll need to support several different types). It gets messy.

I should be able to do this, I think (or at least something pretty similar):

```
callableStatement.setNull(index, Types.ARRAY)
```

But it results in an exception:

> com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function app_fetch_user_list_pkg.n_execute(character varying, character varying[], character varying, boolean, integer) does not exist

Any ideas? (We are working with Postgresql/EDB as well as Oracle... so far, I've been experimenting with the Postgresql instance).

Comment: Have you tried using one of the `setObject` methods that allows you to specify the target type (ie [`setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int targetSqlType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-int-) or [`setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, SQLType targetSqlType)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-java.sql.SQLType-)

Comment: Yes... not much luck. I also tried `setBinaryStream()` and got the rewarding exception message: "This function has not been implemented yet." I'm really not liking this driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm using `PreparedStatement.setNull(position, Types.ARRAY)` with the 9.4-1202-jdbc41 JDBC driver and that is working as expected.

Comment: I suspect you aren't using EDB – seems that a lot of our problems stemmed from EDB. We did manage to get it working (sort of) but ultimately moved to Oracle, and while that caused some upset, everything functioned much more as expected. So... the limitation seems to have been in the EDB drivers.

Comment: @Zac yes, I was using vanilla Postgres. Interesting comment re EDB.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
callableStatement.setString(index, "{}");
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's what happens in my work-around `createArrayOf()` call. However, as I point out, this is not what I'm supposed to do. The database actually dislikes it, throwing back an exception about having passed in an empty array (that's just our API). The best solution is to find out why I can't use the `setNull()` call – I'm starting to think it might be a limitation with our Postgresql/EDB driver.